# Edit a small SQL rowset using forms in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm interested in displaying 1-5 model instances using forms on a page using a grid similar to  something one would find in a desktop database application.  I understand I would need to use multiple forms or formsets but an additional requirement is that I'd prefer it to be in more of a grid format with each model's fields being display in columns with common field labels on the y-axis.

I should have the ability to edit multiple columns (so in effect, model instances) at the same time and then commit either the single column (model instance) or commit all.  I'd also like to be able to highlight the changed cells that have changed to give visual feedback to the user that there are pending changes.

Sorry for the rather long list of requirements and I'm aware this probably requires a few different technologies/techniques to achieve.  I'm throwing this out there because I'm asking this kind community for guidance on what components/technologies I should look at.  If luck would have it, there would be some jQuery component that can handle this for me almost out of the box.  If not, some guidance on achieving the editing of multiple model instances would be of help.

I will also need to build in versioning in case the data displayed on the view page is stale and to prevent overwriting a newer commit.  I'd probably achieve the latter using a versioning field in the table that will perform the check and handle it accordingly.

Also, Flask and Django are both options for the engine and WTForms look to be promising at least at first look.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no such ready to use solution in Django. Just create your custom form that handles as many instances as you want and do anything that you want, or extend formset.